# How to save text file line by line (using python or other editors)

Tags: python, writetofile

I have a text file with 600 lines(\n), and I want to make 600 text files saving each line.
So I want to write text files line by line, but I don't know how I can make it.

e.g. If I have 'all.txt' file with 600 lines, like:
line1 aaaaaa
line2 bbbbbb
line3 cccccc
...
line 600 zzzzzz

-> I want to make results like this:
1.txt (content: aaaaaa)
2.txt (content: bbbbbb)
3.txt (content: cccccc)
...
600.txt (content: zzzzzz)

I have python and notepad++, so it would be really nice to make these results using them.
Thank you so much :)

This is what I tried, but the result was just 'i.txt' file with the last 600th line saved.

```
with open('all.txt',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

```
len(content)
600
```

```
for i, line in enumerate(content):
    with open('i.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(content[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
with open('all.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        with open(f'{i}.txt', 'w') as f2:
            f2.write(line)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! But I got another problem, I think there's an error on encoding,  like this:

Comment: with open('all.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        with open(f'{i}.txt', 'w') as f2:
            f2.write(line)

            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 2, in <module>
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 14: illegal multibyte sequence

Comment: So I added "encoding='utf-8'" these letters, but there's also same error message... my text file is Chinese with utf-8

Comment: @JinNana97 Did you add `encoding='utf-8'` to both calls to `open`?